# Do I need a transit visa through France

Tags: visas, transit, france

I am currently Chinese citizen studying in Canada, I am booking a flight from Canada to Beijing via France. In Paris I have to wait for more than 8 hours for the next connection flight to Beijing. Do I need a Transit Visa in France?

I am not sure whether the baggage claim would make me have to get into the country.

The tag already told me to look for answer in another article, I will move to that.

Comment: I will start my journey in Canada towards Beijing via France, 8 hours in France.

Comment: I thought that's what you probably meant. Could you edit the question (there's a little link below the tags) to include all the relevant information, so people don't have to read through the comments?

Comment: You do realize that Pierre Elliott Trudeau YUL airport is in Canada, don't you?  You say you will be there for 8 hours, and you say that you will be in France for 8 hours, so it appears that you may be confused about the location of YUL airport.

Comment: Hi @phoog, sorry about the confusion, I have removed that bit.